# How to backup and reinsert .bashrc-like files with post-install script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

I have my proudly written *.bashrc* and *.bash-aliases* files. Sometimes, I edit them. More often, I reinstall the whole system.

What is the best and simplest way to preserve content of files (for example: syncing with Dropbox) and then implementing them in new and fresh Ubuntu? Off course, all of that in post-install script.

Comment: Keep it on usb stick perhaps ?

Comment: I want them online, sync-ready and download-ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired with answer provided by [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg) and founding other similar solutions, I have come up with this command, using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeic/ttd/master/.bashrc > .bashrc
```

where `-O` lets you specify the name of the file saving into, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15080782/4455055).

Answer (score 4):

Here's some of the suggestions I can give. Since .bashrc and .bash-aliases are just text files, you can use text storage websites, or just general cloud storage services, like `dropbox`.

**TL;DR** IMHO, the best option is git ( 3rd entry in this post )

**pastebin.com and paste.ubuntu.com**

These websites' purpose is to allow pasting and sharing plain text or code, however you can use it as temporary storage. Typically they keep the entries for up to 2 years.

Knowing a raw link to your paste, you can download that file with `curl`. Here's an example of me using `curl` to download paste of my `.mkshrc` file:

```
serg @ ubuntu $ curl http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8ETyB88j 
PATH=$(echo $PATH:$(find /home/xieerqi/bin -type d -printf "%p:")) 

PS1='serg @ ubuntu $ '

alias ls='ls --color'
alias addx='sudo chmod +x *'
```

As you can see I've downloaded that as plain text, the command also can be redirected to a file , for example `curl http://url.com > filename`

http://textuploader.com/ also allows storing plain text but the maximum I saw is 1 year

**dropbox or other cloud storage**

This is probably better option. The disadvantage is that you probably won't be able to download it with `curl` , but you can still download it with dropbox client, place in the same working directory as whatever set-up script you run, and that should do the job.

**git or other version control software**

git's purpose is to aid developers in " is the management of changes to documents, computer programs, large web sites, and other collections of information " (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)). From my own experience , I've set up a github.com repository, downloaded git ( with `sudo apt-get install git` ) , and uploaded some of my scripts from command line in less than 20 minutes.

Having signed up for github, I've done from command line:

```
git init
git add README.md
git config --global user.email "******@email.com" 
git config --global user.name "username"
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/UserName/repository-name
git push -u origin master
```

And to retrieve stuff:

`git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/repository-name`

It's simple, allows you to keep track of revisions, and more importantly - there's no limit on storage time.

**Special thanks** to uses terdon and A.B. who introduced me to git and github